# jQuery prev and next toggle gallery wont work inside WP Query Loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have an issue going on on a WordPress development that I just can't seem to crack, so any help would be so appreciated. I'm probably missing something so obvious!

I have a WP_Query Loop, which fetches items from a custom Taxonomy called CaseStudies. 
I have a "view more" button below these items that uses Ajax to load more items when clicked. 
Each individual Taxonomy item that is clicked toggles a div over the top of it with its relevant content inside. 
Inside this toggled div I am trying to display a gallery using prev and next buttons. This gallery has been tested on other pages and works perfectly, just not on this page.

It seems that anything i place inside the child DIV of value-swap on this page doesn't show up at all, whether it is my Advanced Custom Fields images or just text.

Here is the code for the loop:

```
 <div id="ajax-posts" class="row">
    <?php
    $args = array(
  'post_type'   => 'casestudies',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
 );

$casestudies = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $casestudies->have_posts() ) :
?>


        <?php
        $postsPerPage = 4;
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'casestudies',
                'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                'cat' => 0
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

    ?>
 <div class="case-open-container">
     <div class="case-toggle">OPEN</div>
         <div class="case-popup">
             <div id="case-carousel" class="case-study-carousel">
                <div class="case-header">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <div class="value-toggle">
            <a id="prev"> PREV </a>
            <a id="next"> NEXT </a>
            </div>
                </div>

            <div class="value-swap">
    <?php $images = get_field('case_gallery'); ?>
    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
    <div class="value-swap-individual">
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                </div>
       <?php endforeach; ?>         
            </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
     </div>

     <?php
            endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
     ?>
      </div>
<?php
else :
  esc_html_e( 'No case studies posted yet!', 'text-domain' );
endif;
?>

</div>
</div>
<div id="more_posts" class="view-more">
    <h3>
        View more work 
    </h3><p class="down-arrow">
    &#x25BC;
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the gallery to prev and next display:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".value-swap div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").click(function(){
    if ($(".value-swap div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".value-swap div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".value-swap div:visible").hide();
        $(".value-swap div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".value-swap div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".value-swap div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
        $(".value-swap div:visible").hide();
        $(".value-swap div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your content is loading from ajax, So just modify your JS from `click` to `on click`.

Because you might have a dynamically generated elements (for example coming from an AJAX call), you might want to have the same click handler that was previously bound to the same element selector, you then "delegate" the click event using on() with selector argument

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".value-swap div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$("#next").on('click',function(){
    if ($(".value-swap div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".value-swap div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
    else {
        $(".value-swap div:visible").hide();
        $(".value-swap div:first").show();
    }
    return false;
});

$("#prev").on('click',function(){
    if ($(".value-swap div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".value-swap div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
        $(".value-swap div:visible").hide();
        $(".value-swap div:last").show();
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Oh amazing!!! That solved it! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this